# How do I remove date and place it in a column using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an export of data that comes out in the following form (dates continue for a month):

```
9/1/2014  
Team        Quantity  
Tom            1  
Jim            2

9/2/2014  
Team        Quantity  
Tom            1  
Jim            2
```

I have to manually remove the date from the top of each line and put it in a column so that I can create a pivot table from it. Is there any VBA code that could take the date from the top row and put it in a column like this:

```
Team       Quantity     Date  
Tom           1          9/1/2014  
Jim           2          9/1/2014 etc...

Team       Quantity     Date  
Tom           1          9/2/2014  
Jim           2          9/2/2014 etc...
```

The only problem is the number of lines that can be under a team is variable every month.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes this would be easy how is the data being put out and such information would help me with you're needs and make this work a lot better. As well is all this data in one column and is it always put into the same excel file say if you make a template Excel file than export the data into the template and save it off so you can always use the same code

Comment: @StortmasterQ that looks a lot different than what was there.

Comment: The data comes out in the first format as listed above.  I can use a template file to paste in the extracted information and use the same vb code.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is what I have for you based off the little Information. I have created you a template and this is how it looks.[image]

You will have to tabs on is to run the program and the other one is where you put you're data in.
[image]

So if you take a look at the data I put in all I would have to do is go push the run button and this is what it will look like.
[image]

So here is the code for the run button.

```
Sub btnRun()
'declare variables
Dim ToBeFound, strVar1, strVar2 As String
Dim rng As Range

ToBeFound = "Team"

'Activate and selete sheet1 than select A1
Sheets("DataTab").Activate
Range("A1").Activate

For x = 1 To 1000
Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=ToBeFound, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If IIf(rng Is Nothing, "", rng) = "" Then
MsgBox "Complete"
Exit Sub

Else
rng.Activate
ActiveCell.Value = "Team:"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Date"
strVar1 = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

For i = 1 To 100
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
Exit For

Else
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = strVar1
End If
Next i
End If
Next x

End Sub
```

And here is the template with everything already complete and done all you do is have to load in the data into the data tab and push run.
http://speedy.sh/twvt3/Template.xlsm